# Redirect multiple files to multiple subfolders using rewrite and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla1.5

.htaccess redirect multiple files to same number in subfolder.

I need to accomplish the following:
receive these request at the main domain (root directory)

```
domain.com/customer-1.html
domain.com/customer-2.html
domain.com/customer-n.html
```

direct them to

```
domain.com/customer-1/
domain.com/customer-2/
domain.com/customer-n/
```

and in sub-directories:

```
 /customer-1/
 /customer-2/
 /customer-n/
```

I need each sub-directory to rewrite the  url to main domain 
      domain.com/customer-n/ ==>http://domain.com

the idea is to serve multiple customer essentially accessing same type of application on their own subdirectory but to the public to show that they are not sharing that domain.

and the subdirectories are all instances of the same joomla install with different templates.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all: it is not a good practice to share a database across multiple customers.
if you mean to share the same codebase, it is ok.

i dont know much about joomla, but must cms support multiple sites.
which mean they can serve independent domains, with the same codebase but different databases.

this may help:

- [Multi Sites](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/5550)
- [MS Control](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/11922)

another thing is to put your customers on a subdomain:

- customer1.example.com
- customerN.example.com

Comment: Thanks for the response, every subfolder (joomla install) will have it's own database, so no code or data sharing. and mostly all visitors will see maindomain.com however will talk to only a subdirectory based on the original url request, so idea of having subdomain is not really a nice option